# ReactDom.render is not rendering modal component to target 2nd time

Tags: reactjs

i am trying to display modal component when user click on a link.

handleShow fn is called when anchor tag is clicked which calls ReactDom.render to display modal.

```
handleShow() {
    ReactDOM.render(<WaiverModal />, document.getElementById("modal"));
  }
```

i could see modal working for 1st time but 2nd time it doesn't pop up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of conditional rendering in react. Instead of making an onClick function to call ReactDOM.render, simply declare a boolean **isClicked** variable in props, and pass it to that onclick function. Then use the JSX syntax to display that component based on your click.

e.g

```
isClicked = false;

<a onClick={!isClicked}></a>


<div>
{ this.props.isClicked && <WaiverModal />  }
</div>
```

Comment: i don't like conditional rendering since i don't find it clean but it seems easy solution for me now. thanks for your soln

Answer (score 0):

I think it's happend because you try to render already the same component second time. How you "unrender" your popup? - this is the question.

So, how you can fix this - create an "modal container" and always render it in some place of page at application start.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./component/App";
import ModalContainer from "./component/ModalContainer";
import "./index.css";

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
ReactDOM.render(<ModalContainer />, document.getElementById("modal"));
```

Then when you want to render some modal - call function and pass the modal component to it.

```
showModal(component) {
    dispatch({ type: APPEND_MODAL, component }),
}
```

Then this function will send this component to some storage (redux for example)

```
import { APPEND_MODAL, HIDE_MODAL } from '../constants/actionTypes';

export default (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case APPEND_MODAL:
      return [
        ...state,
        action.component
      ];
    case HIDE_MODAL:
      return state.slice(0, -1); // Get all exept last
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and then your "modal container" will pick up this component and render it inside.

```
class ModalConainer extends React.Component {
  render() {
  // modals comes from redux - connect ModalContainer to redux store and pass the modals pr
    return this.props.modals.map((component, idx) => (
      <div key={idx}>{component}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

But, sure, you cand find more easy way to do this. It's up to you. Good luck.

Comment: thanks for your help i am writing application in JSX looks like i have to check out Redux.